# Redirect query string with mod_rewrite (vice versa)

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, get

Suppose I have URL's with query string, ie: 
`/DesignPatterns`

Using mod_rewrite, how can I redirect them to:
`/index.php?book=DesignPatterns`

is it correct the following?

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\w+) 
 RewriteRule ^index.php?book=%1? [L,R=301]
```

PS: The original question: How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite? (Feb 12 '10, Patrick McElhaney, I am asking following his permission)

Comment: Your `Rule` is fine but there is small typo in the line

`RewriteRule ^index.php?book=%1? [L,R=301]` . Add a space between `^` and `/index.php?book=%1` otherwise you will get a 500 syntex error. Also your regex capture group `(\w+)` captures limited characters (alpha numbric only) . change it to `(.+)`  if your querystring contains any uri characters.

Comment: So it would be: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?search=%1? [L,R=301] Btw, I'm trying this to clarify any confusion for search bots between a formerly submitted "old" sitemap and a recently submitted "new" sitemap, otherwise they keep sending me 404 messages though I changed my sitemap.  they still keep the former old one as well, apparently, though it's been already months I made this change.

Comment: "URL's with query string, ie:  `/DesignPatterns`" - This is a bit confusing, since this doesn't "look like" a query string. It would be better to post the entire request URL. (Or maybe that is the entire request URL and this isn't a query string after all?). This otherwise implies you have URLs of the form `example.com/foo?/DesignPatterns`. But this contradicts the upvoted and bounty assigned answer, which suggests the URL-snippet posted is in fact the URL-path, not the query string?

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution would be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?search=$1 [L]
```